# how to use output of one function as input of another function in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two functions defined the code of which as below

the output of 1st function is name and ltp. I would this output to be the input of the second function for a data frame. tried few time but could not. Any help welcome.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=None)

def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
global df

for sc in ticks:
    token=sc['instrument_token']
    name=trd_portfolio[token]['name']
    ltp=sc['last_price']

def working (name,ltp):
global df
df1=pd.DataFrame([name,ltp]).T
df1.columns=['name','ltp']
df=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: `ret = a(); ret2 = b(ret)` or more simply `b(a())`

Comment: "could not" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: if you run `for`-loop in `on_ticks` then it can create many `ltp` and you should keep all of them on list - all_ltp.append(ltp). And at the end you should use `return all_ltp`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you execute `on_ticks` but I assume you run it on some mouse click so it has to access `df` using `global` but in `working` I send `df` as argument and get it back with `return` because it is more readable.

I don't get values from `on_ticks` because if it executed by mouse click then it can't use `return` to use it later in `working` but

I run `working` inside `on_ticks` inside `for`-loop to work with every `ltp` separatelly.

```
# --- functions ---

def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
    global df

    for sc in ticks:
        token = sc['instrument_token']
        name = trd_portfolio[token]['name']
        ltp = sc['last_price']
        df = working(df, name, ltp)

def working(df, name, ltp):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame([name, ltp]).T
    new_df.columns = ['name', 'ltp']
    df = df.append(new_df, ignore_index=True)
    return df

# --- main ---

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None)
```

Eventually I would have to get all `ltp` on list and sent this list to `working` and probably `working` would need another `for`-loop to put it in `DataFrame`. And code is longer.

```
# --- functions ---

def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
    global df

    all_name = []
    all_ltp = []

    for sc in ticks:
        token = sc['instrument_token']
        name = trd_portfolio[token]['name']
        all_name.append(name)
        ltp = sc['last_price']
        all_ltp.append(ltp)

    df = working(df, all_name, all_ltp)

def working(df, all_name, all_ltp):
    for name, ltp in zip(all_name, all_ltp):
        new_df = pd.DataFrame([name, ltp]).T
        new_df.columns = ['name', 'ltp']
        df = df.append(new_df, ignore_index=True)

    return df

# --- main ---

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None)
```